# Howto change Angular Material 2 Progress Bar value from code

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm trying to change angular material progressbar value from component code. I need to change the value without using *binding*.

The following logic normally works with htmlcontrols like a text input.
But it doesn't work with progressbar.

**HTML:**

```
    <md-progress-bar mode="determinate" 
    id="progressBar" name="progressBar" #progressBar></md-progress-bar>
<button (click)="test()">Test</button>
```

**Code:**

```
@ViewChild('progressBar') progressBar: any;
test() {
this.progressBar.value = "15";
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to change the value without using a binding? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: This is a SignalR application getting the percentage value from the server. Binding doesn't work in SignalR subscription. and not only for progressbar also for input controls as well but the logic accessing with ViewChild works with input controls. Somehow doesn't work progressbar.

Comment: Binding should work, regardless of where the data comes from. My guess is you are having an issue there because `this.progressBar.value` should also work. Show the real code on how you obtain data and when and where you want the value to change

Comment: @PierreDuc changing programmatically probably isn't working because the progress bar is OnPush, so it only updates the template when values are propagated through the input binding

Comment: @WillHowell Good one, so a `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges` should be called from the parent

Comment: Are you setting the value when component is initialized or afterwards, like on user input?

Comment: no there is a button, I'm setting on onclick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the changedetector solution, as far as I understand this is related with OnPush, now it works. But I had to convert to using binding again. So basically changedetector and binding works fine together.

This is the source code:

```
<md-progress-bar mode="determinate" [value]="percentage" style="width:70%;"
id="progressBar" name="progressBar" #progressBar></md-progress-bar>

    url: string;
    lastSigResult: SigResult;
    @ViewChild('lastSigResultSpan') lastSigResultSpan: any;
    percentage:string = "";
    message:string = "";

    constructor(private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef,private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, private signalRService: SignalRService) {
        this.route.params.subscribe(
            params => {
                console.log(params);
                if (params['url']) { // Eğer url boş değilse
                    this.url = params['url'];
                }
            }
        );

        this.subscribeSignalREvents();
    }

    private subscribeSignalREvents(): void {
        this.signalRService.connectionEstablished.subscribe(() => {
            console.log("Connected to signalr...");
        });
        this.signalRService.messageReceived.subscribe((result: SigResult) => {
            console.log(result);
            // debugger;
            this.changeDetector.markForCheck();
            this.lastSigResult = result;
            this.lastSigResultSpan.nativeElement.value = result.Message;
            this.message = result.Message;
            this.percentage = result.Percentage;
            this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

value must be a number for the progressBar:

```
this.progressBar.value = 15;
```

Comment: it doesn't work as well and also as far as I see from the docs it allows to set like a string as well.